# How do I change my existing SOAP 1.1 client to 1.2?

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-2010

I have a SOAP 1.1 client that was generated with the Delphi 2007 WSDL Importer.

Now I need to change it to SOAP 1.2. Since I changed things in the generated code I prefer not to generate it again. How can I manually change it to SOAP 1.2?

Thanks, Miel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the initialization section of the generated code, for each porttype, add a line like this:

```
InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(PortType), ioSOAP12);
```

That will do the trick.

Miel.